# Python- Why the 'except VauleError' line dose not break while loop?

Tags: python

I am using Ipython Notebook in windows system.The python version is 2.7.

the df is pandas DataFrame and contains only 4 values that beyond that range of load.So as I understand, the 'except VauleError' will be only excuted for 4 times.
But why below code will continue to execute the 'except ValueError ' line and 'print amp_p,amp_n' endlessly? I don't know why but finally I add 'break' after the 'print amp_p,amp_n' and it then works. As I understand,  the 'except ValueError' should able to break the while loop.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import PitchBearing_wohler as pw
load = np.linspace(-8000,8000,num=10,endpoint=True)
result=pd.read_csv('result.csv',header=None)
result[0]
SCF=3.
D=0.
srf=1
f=interpolate.interp1d(load,result[0])
for col in df.columns:
    for ind in df.index:
        cycle=df[col][ind]
        if cycle==0.:
            pass
        else:
            amp_p=float(col)/2.+float(ind)
            amp_n=float(ind)-float(col)/2.
            while True:
                try:
                    range_new=f(amp_p)-f(amp_n)
                    mean_new=(f(amp_p)+f(amp_n))/2
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print amp_p,amp_n,cycle
                    #break # Added after I found the while loop won't break
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `try-catch` block is still inside the scope of the `while` loop. You should place the `while` loop inside your `try` block, instead.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense because after your catched exception, the program will **continue running until the end of except block** and then continue to run the remaining lines while loop after the try-except block until the end (in your case, there isn't anymore) and finally checks if the condition in the while condition remains True. In your case, the condition for the while loop remains True, thus the loop continues.

```
while True:
    try:
        range_new=f(amp_p)-f(amp_n)
        mean_new=(f(amp_p)+f(amp_n))/2
        break
    except ValueError:
        print amp_p,amp_n,cycle
```

One thing you *seem to* misunderstand here is that you think exception should break a while loop while exception actually **does not** break while loop or any loop. If exception happens and it is not catched, it breaks **the program**, not a while loop or any other loops.

If an exception occurs and it is catched, the program will be continued in the except block where it catches the exception.

In either case, it **does not break** while loop, except if your while loop is in the try block and the exception occurs in the try block:

```
try:
    while (x):
        #exception occurs here
except:
```

But even in the above case, strictly speaking, the understanding is still that the exception does **not** break the while loop. It is simply breaks the path of the program and going to the nearest except block.

Comment: thanks for you explanation.I think I know now that Because without the break in the exception block, the while loop will stuck on the same value that create valueerror since the while loop don't move on values in DataFrame, When break added, the program then can jump from while loop to For loop and move on to next value. I just follow some tutorial I searched and don't understand thoroughly and make such mistakes.Thanks.